# My dialog is not showing

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

Using the [UITest on git](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/UITest.java#L114) I'm building a UI. However the popup dialog is not showing, at least I think it is a popup dialog window. Here i setup the button that should open it:

```
    ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButtonStyle(skin.get(ButtonStyle.class));
    style.imageUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(image);
    style.imageDown = new TextureRegionDrawable(imageFlipped);
    ImageButton iconButton = new ImageButton(style);
```

Here is the Listener attached to it:

```
    iconButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() 
    {
        public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) 
        {
            new Dialog("Some Dialog", skin, "dialog") 
            {
                protected void result (Object object) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Chosen: " + object);
                }
            }.text("Are you enjoying this demo?").button("Yes", true).button("No", false).key(Keys.ENTER, true)
                .key(Keys.ESCAPE, false).show(stage);
        }
    });
```

The button itself is working properly, when i click and hold it flips but when i release this dialog stops functioning (probably because the other dialog needs attention). I can press enter/ESC and get the corresponding results in the console (Chosen: true/Chosen: false). However i can not exit this since i am not able to see the actual dialog.

I am not using everything from the [git example](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/1.3.0/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/UITest.java) like password box and dropdown. I'm also implementing it as a stand alone class and just creating it as a object in the root class. I do not see a problem with that but then again, what do i know :)?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, could not be fixed as the question is currently stated:

```
//I had this in my render method:
stage.act(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1/30));
//Should be
stage.act(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1/30f));
//Otherwise it would always be 0, and i guess that would pause the whole stage.
```